# Alterar tipo 'None' de um dicionário em python

Tags: python, string, dicionário

Preciso alterar o valor de uma chave de um dicionário, cujo valor vem como 'None'.

Exemplo: `a = {b: 'qualquer', c: 'qualquer'}`, sendo que esse é meu dicionário em python.

Sendo que `'qualquer'` se refere a valores aleatórios, sendo que também pode vir valores do tipo `None`. Não posso fazer a modificação de modo geral, pois não sei quando irá vir valor do tipo `None` ou não.

Agora eu quero pegar o valor de `a['b']` tal que, `a['b'] !=  None`. Ou sendo mais preciso, quando `a['b'] == None` fazer virar um string vazia, ou seja, `a['b'] == ""`.

Eu tentei utilizar a função `re.sub()` , mas sem sucesso:

`a['b'] = re.sub(None, "", a['b'])`

Comment: Resumindo, você quer que todos os valores que forem `None` no seu dicionário virem uma string vazia?

Comment: @sourcream não todos, mas 1 especifico. Sendo que nesse exemplo é determinado pela chave 'b'.

Comment: Amigo, desculpa, não consigo entender o que tu queres... Tu poderias tentar explicar melhor o problema?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado quando o valor vir `None` em `a['b']` quero que vire uma string vazia. Assim como deixei claro no enunciado.

Comment: Para isso, basta testar esse campo específico... Um simples `if` faz isso...

Comment: `a["b"] if a["b"] is not None else ""`

Comment: Olha, pensei que não iria funcionar. Pois o valor estava sendo atribuido a um elemento de outro dicionário. Eu sempre utilizo esses testes, mas estava pensando em alguma coisa diferente. Mas no fim, deu certo rsrs. O que eu mais utilizo não estava testando. De qualquer maneira, value demais @LeonardoAlvesMachado.

Comment: Adicione ao campo de respostas, para que assim eu possa escolhe-la.

Answer (score -1):

Se temos um dicionário do tipo:
`a = {b: 'qualquer', c: 'qualuqer'}` onde `qualquer` diz respeito a qualquer entrada aleatório, então para que `a['b']` quando for `None` ser substituido por uma string vazia, do tipo `""`, basta fazer o seguinte teste com `if`..

`a["b"] if a["b"] is not None else ""`

Sendo assim, se `a['b']` for `None` irá ser substituido por `""`.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).